# Converting a Hex Value to a string while Reading from a BIN

Tags: c#, parsing, binary

I am writing a program in C# to modify and manipulate binary files for purposes of Automotive computing...I am running into an issue when simply trying to display to the user a hex value for certain address (I've gotten the program to modify the file as necessary and now I am trying to make it more user friendly) I've gotten the program to write the entire file in HEX to a textBox, but for some reason I'm having issues when trying to display one value. Here is the code, you can see that I have commented out the section that used to display the entire file...

```
// Opens the stream, notice that this case only has.Read appended to it, we
// don't want to harm the original binary file
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(chosenFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    // returns the number of bytes in the file...
    size = (int)stream.Length; 
    // Initializes the array in which to store the data bytes...
    data = new byte[size];
    // Writes the binary data to a particular file...
    // In this case the data[] array
    stream.Read(data, 0, size); 
    progressBar1.Maximum = size;

    // Prints the original binary file...
    while (printCount < size) 
    {
        int i = data[printCount];
        // Formats the data to the same format as the hex editor...
        // not sure exactly why it works...
        // string h = i.ToString("x2"); 
        // richTextBox1.Text += h + "-";

        if (printCount1 == 15)
        {
            // richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            printCount1 = 0;
        }
        if (stream.Position == 32)
        {
            pinByte1 = i.ToString("x2");
        }
        if (stream.Position == 33)
        {

            pinByte2 = i.ToString();
            // Now stores the reversed location of the two,
            // convert to decimal for pin...
            pin = pinByte2 + pinByte1;

        }

        printCount++;
        printCount1++;
        progressBar1.Increment(1);

        textBox1.Text = "Please wait, reading original BIN...";
    }
    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox1.Text = "Your file has been read, proceed to unlock...";
    textBox2.Text += pinByte1;
    textBox3.Text += pinByte2;
    textBox6.Text += pin;
}
```

Comment: If the value you're interested in is at a specific location in the file, is there a reason why you aren't using the [`FileStream.Seek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx) method?

Comment: Also, not really an answer to your question, but it looks like you're trying to do file I/O from the UI thread.  You really shouldn't do that: it will likely lead to dreaded "this application is not responding" messages from Windows.  Plus, with the code the way it is now, your users will never see any progress bar updates, since you never let the message pump run while this method is running.  Instead, you should do all the file I/O in a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Comment: What is the issue? What is it displaying? What do you want it to display?